# How to properly import modules in a Pycharm project?

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm

I have some issues importing some modules in my latest project. I'm really new to Pycharm and Python and I could really use the help/insight.

The problem is I have a folder of utils i wanna use but I cant seem to import modules correctly. Here is what my directories look like roughly:

```
myproject
   utils
      utilities
         myclass.py
         __init__.py
         anothermodule
            __init__.py
            src
               helper_func.py
               __init__.py
   venv
      ...
      main.py
      ...
```

I wanna be able to use my classes and functions in the following way:

```
object = utilities.myclass.myclass( . . . )
thing =  utilities.anothermodule.src.helper_func.helper_func ( . . .)
```

I thought the way to go would be just to :

```
from utils import utilities
```

But trying to create ''object'' as previously stated gives me this error (myclass.py contains a class called ''myclass''):

```
AttributeError: module 'utils.utilities' has no attribute 'myclass'
```

I have already marker utils, utilities , anothermodule, src as Source roots in Pycharm. What am I doing wrong? I also already added the path of the folder ''utils'' to the sys paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `utilities/__init__.py` file add the following.

```py
from . import myclass
from . import anothermodule
```

and `anothermodule` should import `src` and `src` should import `helper_func` and so on.

when you import utilities, python imports the `__init__` file under the name of `utilities`, this is because folders are imported as packages.

another alternative is just doing the following, but you'll have to modify the syntax.

```py
from utils.utilities import myclass
myclass.myclass()
# or
import utils.utilities.my_class
utils.utilities.myclass.myclass()
```

you can find more information about this in python [package documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages)